# I need help with a microphone issue for my aviation headset

Tags: impedance, microphone, electret

This is my first time asking for help in a forum so I hope I can do it properly.

My problem is this:

I have an aviation headset with a non working microphone and I would like to try make a microphone for it myself.

The headset has 2 x 300ohm speakers wired in parallel and had a noise canceling electret microphone of 150 ohms.

I can get the electret microphone capsules but they are either 1k ohm or 2.2k ohm impedance. When i wire it up straight to the headset, the microphone works but is too soft.

My question is this , how can I reduce the 1k or 2.2k electret microphone impedance down to 150 ohm impedance so it will work with my headset???

Comment: You better show link to mic specs an radio

Comment: Does the microphone have two terminals or three?

Answer (score 1):

[In this material](https://www.yumpu.com/en/document/read/24512795/guide-for-electret-condenser-microphones-escoth):

> The sensitivity is defined as the output voltage for a specified
> acoustic stimulus and load condition. In this catalog it is expressed
> in dBV/pa (dBV/10µbar). In the case of dynamic types it is expressed
> as the open circuit voltage appearing at the output terminals. In the
> case of electret type it is expressed with a specified resistive load
> and supply voltage since the output resistance tends towards constant
> current characteristic.
>
> The output impedance represents the internal electric resistance
> within a microphone as seen from the side of output terminals of the
> microphone. JIS C-5502 specifies 50,200,250,400 and 600 ohms as
> standard. In the case of ECMs, the effective output resistance is
> determined mainly by the value of load resistance. It can be made
> higher or lower by the value of load resistance with a corresponding
> change in sensitivity.

It sounds like you need to try 200 ohms, that is close to 150 ohm. You can try a 500 ohm resistor in series (not parallel, don't ask why) with the microphone.

Hope you can have a spare one soon. It could be a safety concern while you are flying.

Answer (score 1):

Electret mics have a built-in FET with a common source and the drain pullup determines the DC level and the gain.  Buffering the impedance with an emitter follower if loaded by 200 Ohms will work.

Or if not loaded , Choosing a larger R pullup and if needed a higher Vcc will increase gain but also the Dc operating point and may be offset from Vcc/2. Thus increasing Vcc may be needed.

Consider this solution: https://www.thomasnet.com/catalogs/productline/30801253-18459-1155/pilot-communications-usa/amplified-electret-noise-canceling-microphones/

Comment: It’s unlikely that the OP will be able (or wish to) change the phantom power voltage, as this is typically supplied by the radio.  Changing the pull-up resistor to a smaller value is likely to be the best option.

Comment: A smaller resistor on the drain of an electret mic will reduce the gain.

Comment: you’re quite right, the FET will be predominantly in the constant-current region

Comment: I thought the VCC & pullup is likely included in the radio, Mic. only has two terminals. Should ask @Royden. If that is the story, 150ohm meant the mic. internal FET has to drive 150ohm load. So, no option there. Gain improvement cannot be done anyway, but probably a series register give some relief to the FET operation point.